# Using Google Cloud platform's Compute Engine

Tags: google-compute-engine

I would like to know what is Google Cloud's service availability? When the platform is down, how long does it take to restore the services? Is there a proof of documentation for it?

I urgently need this information but I can't seem to find it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find the Incidents reported in the last 365 days [1], and how long they lasted.

You can check GCP's available zones and regions on this documentation [2].

Here is were to check the Platform's products status(es) reports [3].

Finally you can check the SLA of the products [4] here.

I also wanted to share this document about building robust system [5] with you.

Best Wishes!

---

[1] https://status.cloud.google.com/summary

[2] https://cloud.google.com/about/locations

[3] https://status.cloud.google.com/

[4] https://cloud.google.com/terms/sla

[5] https://cloud.google.com/solutions/scalable-and-resilient-apps